# Understanding no free lunch theorem in Duda et al's Pattern Classification

Tags: machine-learning

I have some questions about the notations used in Section *9.2 Lack of Inherent Superiority of Any Classifier* in Duda, Hart and Stork's *[Pattern Classification](http://books.google.com/books?id=YoxQAAAAMAAJ&q=duda+pattern+classification&dq=duda+pattern+classification&hl=en&sa=X&ei=3Jo2T4eMM8bZ0QHm4pSBBQ&ved=0CE0Q6AEwAg)*. First let me quote some relevant text from the book:

> - For simplicity consider a two-category problem, where the training    set $D$ consists of patterns $x^i$ and associated category labels    $y_i = ± 1$ for $i = 1,..., n$ generated by the unknown target function to be learned, $F(x)$, where $y_i = F(x^i)$.
> - Let $H$ denote the (discrete) set of hypotheses, or possible sets of    parameters to be learned. A particular hypothesis $h(x) \in H$
>     could    be described by quantized weights in a neural network, or
>     parameters    0 in a functional model, or sets of decisions in a tree,
>     and so on.
> - Furthermore, $P(h)$ is the prior probability that the algorithm will    produce hypothesis $h$ after training; note that this is not
>     the    probability that $h$ is correct.
> - Next, $P(h|D)$ denotes the probability that the algorithm will yield     hypothesis $h$ when trained on the data $D$. In
>     deterministic    learning algorithms such as the nearest-neighbor and
>     decision trees,    $P(h|D)$ will be everywhere zero except for a
>     single hypothesis $h$.    For stochastic methods (such as neural
>     networks trained from random    initial weights), or stochastic
>     Boltzmann learning, $P(h|D)$ can be a    broad distribution.
> - Let $E$ be the error for a zero-one or other loss function.
>
> The expected off-training-set classification error when the true
>   function is $F(x)$ and the probability for the $k$th candidate
>   learning algorithm is $P_k(h(x)|D)$ is given by $$
>  \mathcal{E}_k(E|F,n) = \sum_{x\notin D} P(x) [1-\delta(F(x), h(x))]
>  P_k(h(x)|D) $$
>
> **Theorem 9.1. (No Free Lunch)** For any two learning algorithms $P_1 (h |D)$ and $P_2(h|D)$, the following are true, independent of the
>   sampling distribution $P(x)$ and the number $n$ of training points:
>
> 1. Uniformly averaged over all target functions $F$, $\mathcal{E}_1 (E|F, n) — \mathcal{E}_2(E|F, n) = 0$
> 2. For any fixed training set $D$, uniformly averaged over $F$,  $\mathcal{E}_1 (E|F, D) — \mathcal{E}_2(E|F, D) = 0$
>
> Part 1 is actually saying $$\sum_F \sum_D P(D|F) [\mathcal{E}_1 (E|F,
>  n) — \mathcal{E}_2(E|F, n)] = 0$$
>
> Part 2 is actually saying $$\sum_F  [\mathcal{E}_1 (E|F, D) —
>  \mathcal{E}_2(E|F, D)] = 0$$

**My questions are**

1. In the formula of $\mathcal{E}_k(E|F,n)$, i.e. $$
       \mathcal{E}_k(E|F,n) = \sum_{x\notin D} P(x) [1-\delta(F(x), h(x))]
       P_k(h(x)|D), $$ can I replace $P_k(h(x)|D)$ with $P_k(h|D)$ and move it outside the sum $\sum_{x \notin D}$, because
   it is really a distribution of $h$ over $H$ given $D$ for the $k$th
   stochastic learning algorithm?
2. Given that the $k$th candidate learning algorithm is a stochastic
   method, why in the formula of $\mathcal{E}_k(E|F,n)$, there is no
   sum over $h$, i.e. $\sum_{h \in H}$?
3. How are $\mathcal{E}_i (E|F, D)$ and $\mathcal{E}_i (E|F, n)$ 
   different from each other?

   Does $\mathcal{E}_i (E|F, D)$ mean the off-training error rate given
   a training set $D$?

   Does $\mathcal{E}_i (E|F, n)$ mean the off-training error rate,
   average over all training set given a training size $n$? If yes, why
   does part 1 in NFL theorem average $\mathcal{E}_i (E|F, n)$ over
   training sets again by writing $\sum_D$, and why in the formula for
   $\mathcal{E}_k(E|F,n) $, there is no average over all training set
   given a training size $n$?
4. In part 1 of NFL theorem, does $\sum_D$ mean summing over all
   training sets with a fixed training size $n$?
5. If further summing over all possible values in $\mathbb{N}$ of training size $n$ in part 1, the result is still 0, right?
6. In the formula of $\mathcal{E}_k(E|F,n)$, if I change $\sum_{x
   \notin D}$ to $\sum_x$, i.e. $x$ is not necessarily restricted to be
   outside the training set, will both parts in NFL theorem still be
   true?
7. If the true relation between $x$ and $y$ are not assumed to be a
   deterministic function $F$ as $y=F(x)$, but instead conditional
   distributions $P(y|x)$, or a joint distribution $P(x,y)$ which is
   equivalent to knowing $P(y|x)$ and $P(x)$ (also see [my another question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22654/is-the-true-relation-between-independent-and-dependent-variables-assumed-to-be-a)), then I can change
   $\mathcal{E}_k (E|F,n)$ to be $$ \mathcal{E}_k(E|P(x,y),n) =
   \mathcal{E}_{x,y} [1-\delta(y, h(x))] P_k(h(x)|D) $$ (with the strange $P_k(h(x)|D)$ pointed out in part 1 and 2).   Are the
   two parts in NFL theorem still true?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: Is $\delta$ the Dirac/Kronecker-delta? In$$
 \mathcal{E}_k(E|F,n) = \sum_{x\notin D} P(x) [1-\delta(F(x), h(x))]
 P_k(h(x)|D) $$

Comment: Is this No Free Lunch theorem the same as the Halting problem ? Are they connected ?

Answer (score 9):

I will answer the questions that I think I know the answers to.

1. This answer is no because you are picking an $x$ that wasn't part of the fit set $D$ and so $h$ depends on $x$.
2. $h$ is only evaluated at the values $x$ in the test set to obtain the expected error rate so it is not evaluated over the entire set $H$ but only at the discrete set of $x$'s in the test set.
3. $\mathcal{E}_i(E|F, D)$ is the expected off training set error rate given the function $F$ and the training set $D$.  But $\mathcal{E}_i(E|F, n)$ I think is different because you are only conditioning on the number of training points $n$ and not the actual $x$ values. But this is puzzling given the subsequent statements.
4. $D$ is the set of training vectors.  There are $n$ training vectors in $D$.  So you are summing over the fixed $n$ training vectors in $D$.  There is only one set $D$.
5. I think the answer to 5 is no.  The notation seems to be a bit confusing.

Can't comment on 6 and 7.

Comment: +1. Welcome to the site, I'm a big fan of your reviews on Amazon. Excuse my presumption in editing, mathematical notation is mostly done by putting $'s on both sides of something. If you click on the yellow-circle-? in the upper right when writing, you'll see a link for "advanced help" which will give more info; also, you can right-click on some existing mathjax (such as any of the above) & select "Show Math As -> TeX commands" to see how it was done.

Comment: In other words, @gung is saying: This site supports $\LaTeX$ in (almost) exactly the way you'd expect it to, including display math. Welcome to the site.

Comment: @Michael Please allow me to add my welcome to these others: I am delighted to see you here.  (Michael has made exceptionally knowledgeable contributions on American Statistical Association discussion lists.)