# Are the No Free Lunch Theorem and Halting Problem connected?

Tags: algorithms

I just read about the [no free lunch theorem](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22648/understanding-no-free-lunch-theorem-in-duda-et-als-pattern-classification) where it is said:

> Uniformly averaged over all target functions $F$, $\mathcal{E}_1 (E|F,
> > n) — \mathcal{E}_2(E|F, n) = 0$

The words **"all target functions"**, reminded me of the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem):

> In computability theory, the halting problem is the problem of
>   determining, from a description of an arbitrary computer program and
>   an input, whether the program will finish running or continue to run
>   forever. Alan Turing proved in 1936 that a general algorithm to solve the halting problem for **all possible program-input pairs** cannot exist.

This made me wonder if the two are related, if yes, how ?

EDIT:

Here is a different reason why they might be connected:

-Intelligence is a form of (lossy) compression

-Measure of compressability is Kolmogorov complexity

-Calculating the Kolmogorov complexity for an arbitrary string is undecidible (-> Halting problem)

(One flaw with this similarity that the Kolmogorow complexity is defined for lossless compression, while Intelligence is a form of lossy compression).

Comment: Quick google search gives this : https://www.researchgate.net/publication/4074735_On_the_connection_between_the_no_free_lunch_theorem_and_the_trivial_property_for_recursively_enumerable_languages

Comment: and this : http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/59608/does-the-the-undecidability-of-the-halting-problem-eliminate-the-possibility-of

Comment: Intelligence is not a form of lossy compression.  See https://vimeo.com/17553536

Comment: The best way to compress data is to discover the way it was generated and use that algorithm to generate it. For example the digits of PI. Any physics equation. Any working scientific theory. Speech. Vision. Is there an example where this does not hold ? For example, if I want to understand language /speech then I need to compress the probability distribution of all heard sentences. This compression will lead to a model of language / world that describes how speech is generated. Is there an example where this viewpoint does not hold ?

Comment: The vimeo link describes lossless, as opposed to lossy, compression, as a universal measure of intelligence.  Any set of data will have noise.  Even if you know the algorithm that generated the data, your measurement instrument will introduce noise.  You can't throw the noise away because one man's noise is another man's ciphertext.  Throwing away noise is indistinguishable from confirmation bias.

Comment: Interesting point. Perhaps a main question is to define what is noise, or figuring out how to define it. That is an important part of "practical/everyday" intelligence : vision, speech recognition, machine translation. Throwing away noise = define noise. Perhaps defining what is noise and what is not is itself the same as "everyday intelligence" because to do that one has to figure out the model already. Defining what is noise cannot happen without defining the model, and vica versa. So yeah. Defining what is noise and what is not noise is an interesting question in itself, indeed.

Comment: This is somehow connected to the no-free-lunch theorem, defining what is noise and what is not seems to solve that (by a bias). So somehow figuring out this bias (in a meaningful way, what is meaningful ? - for example to create better surviving biological robots) could be in itself the definition of practical intelligence. Practical in the sense that it tries to solve a task (such as better survival/replication).

Comment: The only way you can be sure you have distinguished noise from something you should model is to find the Kolmogorov Complexity of the data.  You don't need to resort to the no free lunch theorem for this.  You simply need to accept the incomputability of the Kolmogorov Complexity of the data.  In other words, you can never be certain that your "noise" is noise.

Answer (score 3):

No they are not related. In NFL, a function can be considered as a look-up-table (that is, a list of input-output pairs.) We are not concerned with how a function is implemented with NFL. With computability theory, we are concerned with how a function is actually computed.

try Woodward J. Computable and Incomputable Search Algorithms and Functions. IEEE International Conference on Intelligent Computing and Intelligent Systems (IEEE ICIS 2009) November 20-22,2009 Shanghai, China. pdf.